# jQuery $.change function not working with cloned select

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, onchange

I have a table with a button that adds a row to the bottom by cloning the last row. Each row contains a `<select>` with a different name (0-9), all `<select>` objects have the `.variable_priority` class. When pressing the button, the row gets copied successfully and I manage to change the name correctly (10, 11, 12, etc.), and the row gets the same class since it is a perfect copy.

However, when I execute the following function, I encounter problems with cloned table rows:

```
$('.variable_priority').change(function() {
    var selections = new Array();
    $(".variable_priority").each(function() {
        selections.push($(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });

    // Iterating on Options of Select
    $('.variable_priority').children('option').each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');

        if($.inArray($(this).val(), selections) !== -1){
            if($(this).val() != 0){
                if($(this).is(':selected')){
                    // nothing
                } else {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The function should run each time I change the selected option of a `<select>`, though it only runs with the 10 original ones. This function is not executed when I change the option in a cloned row. However, if I change the value in one of the originals, the function runs and it also adds the values from the cloned rows to the `selections` array.

So for some reason, the code recognizes that the clones have the same class, but it doesn't run when changing their values.

EDIT: short description of the code above; if I change the selected value of a `<select>`,the function will add all selected options to an array and disable every selected option in the selects, except in the box where the value itself is selected (if I select '2' in the first box, '2' gets disabled in all other boxes).

Comment: try using 
$(document).on("change",".variable_priority",function(){

});

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `select` element is dynamic (It is added to the DOM *after* the initial page load, or to be specific; *after* the initial event handler attachment) you will need to delegate your `change` event handler:

```
$(document).on('change', '.variable_priority', function() {

});
```

Rather than use `document` though, you'll want to attach the event handler to the closest static element to `.variable_priority`.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3qeznen1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code isn't executed on the new clones.

This script is loaded on start. It has to do it over for each new children.. Maybe after adding a new, run this script specific for that new one.

Comment: I already had this code included, but it was not sufficient to solve every problem. In combination with George's answer it worked though!